# Using very large bitmap textures with OPENGL 2.0 Android

Tags: android, opengl-es, bitmap, textures, opengl-es-2.0

I have an application which views zoomable images using OPENGLES2.0, and want to render large textures - 1920x2560 and larger - and get GL_INVALID_VALUE errors when trying to load them.

How do I go about doing this?

Comment: First thing to do would be checking highest supported texture size (GL_MAX_TEXTURE_SIZE).

Comment: The value is 3379 - does that mean the max size in bytes is 3379?
Even so that doesn't answer my question about how i do display those large images.

Comment: @saarraz1 It is (or should be according to specification) the resolution, meaning 3379x3379.

Answer (score 1):

Mobile devices often cannot support textures bigger than 2048 pixels (width or height).

IOS devices such as IPAD for instance cannot support textures bigger than 2048x2048.

I have found the same limit on most of the Android devices where I have tested my PATRIA 3D engine hence I can only advice you to stay under this limit.

I suggest you to read carefully this official OpenGL document
http://www.opengl.org/resources/faq/technical/texture.htm

In particular point:

21.130 What's the maximum size texture map my device will render hardware accelerated?